# Saving arrays within the loop with different name

Tags: python, arrays, loops, save

I have a question related to the saving an array(.npy).

I have a computation that produces a new array for every loop.
Once a while (let's say every 10 steps) I would like to save my output into .npy with a specific name, let's say result_at_step_10.npy. Of course at steps 20, the file name should be result_at_step_20.npy
how could I do that in python?

Comment: I would recommend you using a library called pandas. It's easy to use and does pretty much everything you can think of :)

Comment: Could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If renaming the file is what your are looking for, here is the code

```
import os
os.rename("old_name","new_name")
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, that is not what I need it. Instead of renaming the array, what I want is saving it with another name. 

Maybe this an example what I want

for i in range (0,100):
     a = i+1
     (and here is the code that I do not know) save (a) = a_at_i.npy